# How to use Open Sans font with cakePhp 3?

Tags: css, fonts, zurb-foundation, cakephp-3.0, google-font-api

I'm using cakePhp 3.0.4 to build my application. As i understand, cakePhp 3 uses Zurb Foundation and i do not understand how to change default font(sans-serif)

default font is spesified in base.css file line 11:

```
/*  font-family: sans-serif; *//* 1 */
font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
```

What i have tried so far:
1. Load font in base.css first line: `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);`

2. Change base.css `font-family to 'Open sans', sans-serif;`

Also i have tried:

1. load the font in default.ctp:

   $this->Html->css('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700')
2. Change base.css font-family to 'Open sans', sans-serif;

No success so far. Howto use Open sans -font correctly in cakePhp 3 application?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `CSS` or `SCSS`?

Comment: It's really hard to help without seeing the rest of your css but are you overriding Foundations default font-family which is Helvetica?

Comment: Also if base.css is called before your foundation.css it will likely override anything font wise as it uses Helvetica. If you're look to customise Foundation I would use the SCSS version instead: http://www.regbirch.com/blog/cakephp-zurb-foundation-livereload

Comment: Please see whole base.css http://pastebin.com/kkzJP3DP

Comment: Ahhh you're trying to change Normalize. Answe below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the Zurb copyright comment add:

`@import {url(fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans); }`

Then within the Foundation code find each instance of:

`font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

and change it to:

`font-family:"Open Sans","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

I've left in the Helvetica so if Google Fonts fail it will fall back to that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to hear it mate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `font-family: 'Open Sans';` instead of `font-family: 'Open-sans';`

If you open the url of the google font api:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700

The name you have to use is set by

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  ...
}
```

Comment: no success yet. on base.css first line @import {url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans); }and then  {@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
} }Did not work